# Administrator rights request

Tags: delphi, windows-vista, c++builder, vcl

I've got error if I don't run my program "As Administrator"
***Access violation*** ... in module ... etc...

Got error when trying to work with my ini file.
How to avoid error or make a request Administrator rights.

(using C++Builder6 , but Delphi code is readable for me too)

working with ini by default

```
TIniFile *FormCllient;
        FormCllient = new TIniFile(ExtractFilePath(Application->ExeName)+"Inf\\MyIniFile.ini");
...
```

**Added :**

I think I need add rules for folder after install application 
I make install pack with Inno Setup ... Hope that's real.

*****Added : *****

How to put my file into app data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function I wrote to get the Application Data folder in C++Builder.

If you're using older versions of C++Builder, you might find you have to change this to use AnsiStrings instead of Unicode (replace the "`UnicodeString`"s with "`AnsiString`"s, and change the call to "`SHGetSpecialFolderPathW`" to read "`SHGetSpecialFolderPath`").

GetAppDataFolder.h:

```
#ifndef GetAppDataFolderH
#define GetAppDataFolderH

UnicodeString GetAppDataFolder(bool roaming = true);

#endif
```

GetAppDataFolder.cpp:

```
// Helper function to get the location of the current user's Application Data folder (used for
// storing per-user application settings).

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop


/*  roaming:    True for application data that can be accessed by the same user on different
                machines. If you have per-user settings that are only relevant to a particular
                computer, e.g., screen resolution, set 'roaming' to false.
*/
UnicodeString GetAppDataFolder(bool roaming /* = true */)
{
    UnicodeString retVal;
    int csidl = roaming ? CSIDL_APPDATA : CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA;
    wchar_t thePath[MAX_PATH];
    if (SHGetSpecialFolderPathW(NULL, thePath, csidl, 0) == TRUE) {
        retVal = thePath;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't put the ini file along the application /unless you really have to/. The common user, even the administrator /when app not explicitly elevated/ has no right to write into the Program Files folder.
Use environment var %ProgramData% if you want to write the ini accessible for all users, and use env var %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming if you want to write user specific data accessible only by the current user.
You can use also "[SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181(VS.85).aspx)" in order to obtain these folder via API.

Comment: "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming" will work a little bit ugly in WinXP. SHGetFolderPath is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Try hard coding it, the access violation is probably coming from asking the system for information about a file that the user may or may not have permissions to know about. if you need a more dynamic solution try using an environment variable that refers to the location of the file or the users "home" folder

Comment: I think I need to move my ini file to {localappdata} 
The path to the local (nonroaming) Application Data folder.

Answer (score 0):

Any reasons for/against storing your app configuration in the registry?  I'm not suggesting you redo the code that brought up the question, just curious for my own future projects.